# Mocking type-casting objects

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, mocking, mockito

I have a simple method in my bean to handle cell edit event in primefaces datatable. Method looks like this:

```
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
    Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

    User user = (User) ((DataTable) event.getComponent()).getRowData();
    if (!newValue.equals(oldValue))
    user.setUsername(oldValue.toString());
                     ....
}
```

How do I mock this: 
`User user = (User) ((DataTable) event.getComponent()).getRowData();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CellEditEvent mockEvent = Mockito.mock(CellEditEvent.class);
DataTable mockDataTable = Mockito.mock(DataTable.class);

Mockito.when(mockEvent.getComponent()).thenReturn(mockDataTable);
Mockito.when(mockDataTable.getRowData()).thenReturn(userObj);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to mock both the [`CellEditEvent`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/event/CellEditEvent.html) and the [`Datatable`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTable.html):

```
public class EventTest {

    //Let's supose that's the managed bean you want to test
    public class Bean {
        public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
            User user = (User) ((DataTable) event.getComponent()).getRowData();
            System.out.println(user);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Bean bean = new Bean();
        CellEditEvent evt = Mockito.mock(CellEditEvent.class);
        DataTable table = Mockito.mock(DataTable.class);
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Bob");
        Mockito.when(table.getRowData()).thenReturn(new User("Username"));
        Mockito.when(evt.getComponent()).thenReturn(table);
        bean.onCellEdit(evt);
    }
}
```

**See also:**

- [Mockito documentation](http://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html)