# How to Mock Objects which are typecasted?

Tags: java, mockito

```
public class Details extends SubDetails{

}

public String getString(Details details){
    SubDetails subDetails = (SubDetails) details;
}
```

How to mock type-casting in above case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking type-casting objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628863/mocking-type-casting-objects)

Comment: like you mock normal objects?

Comment: The cast in `SubDetails subDetails = (SubDetails) details;` is unnecessary if `Details extends SubDetails`.

Comment: @ShanuGupta I tried Mock SubDetails subDetails I have no idea how to write  when statement

Comment: What I meant was if `details` is mocked, your `subDetails` will be mocked as well.

Comment: @ShanuGupta  try doing that in your ide,I already did it is giving me an error

Comment: I don't have the setup currently, whats the error?

Comment: @JustinAlbano That answer won't work for me, Please look at it they are two different scenarios

Comment: The whole example seems really unclear; could you share some real code you're working with?

Comment: @YashwanthPotu Are you using a mocking framework (e.g. Mockito) or are you instantiating a mock object yourself (i.e. `Details mockDetails = new SubDetails()`)?

Comment: @JustinAlbano I satisfied by using spy, It worked Thanks for all the help guys

Comment: @YashwanthPotu post your answer as well.

Comment: @ShanuGupta It's better if I can use  Mock rather than spy, I got no ideas